# Python3.5 import program.py error

Tags: file, python-3.5, python-import

can not import a python program in the same folder

C:\Users\User_Unknowed\Desktop\Marvin

So i have started to just look if it where the fun.py that could be wrong or it can't just be find which now print error so i need help.

My code on test67.py:

## start of code

```
import os.path

if not os.path.exists(fun.py):
     print("Alarm")

if os.path.exists(fun.py):
     print("import")
```

## end of code

Anything of an solution would be lovely. Answer as quickly as possible please, thx.

Comment: are you having trouble importing fun.py to test67.py or having trouble locating if it exists??

Comment: if its in the same folder you just do "import fun" at the top

Comment: Importing it but I also need to learn locat files as well, and I have tried to import fun & import fun.py and that's why I am trying to locat fun.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a file inside of the same directory use:

```
import fun
```

To locate the file in a specified directory use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

```
import os

def find(nameofFile, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if nameofFile in files:
            return os.path.join(root, nameofFile)
```

if you find this file is not in the same directory you can use sys.path.insert() to add the path of the file you want to import:

```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, pathtoFile)
   from fun import *
```

Hope this helps.